# Retaining old value of html input

Tags: jquery, html, input

There is a requirement where I need to get the old value of input box.

```
<input type ="text" name="" onFocus=(this.name=this.value) onchange='doSomething(this.value,this.name)'/>
```

This needs to be done in two cases.

1. `onFocus`
2. when input html element renders

Can it be done on autofocus; is below line of code is valid.

There is a requirement where I need to get the old value of input box.

```
<input type ="text" name="" onFocus=(this.name=this.value) autofocus=(this.name=this.value) onchange='doSomething(this.value,this.name)'/>
```

Will I get the value if I read name `attr` of input.

```
$(input).attr("name");
```

if not ; is there any other help.

Comment: take a look at `this.defaultValue`

Comment: You haven't got a name on the input? So what name?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney typo mistake

Comment: Why would you ever want to change the `name` of a form element to match its value? Surely your server-side code depends on the `name` always being the same?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan to retain old value. requirements make your hands dirty

Comment: In that case use a `data` attribute for a custom value.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can u give an example.

Answer (score 0):

As per @RoryMcCrossan's suggestion, you could try using the jQuery .data() method to store the value into a data attribute on focus, e.g.

HTML:

```
<input data-myoldvalue="" value="My First Value" />
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery("input").on("focus", function(e) {
   var elem = jQuery(e.target);
   console.log('oldval', elem.data('myoldvalue')); //Some debugging code
   elem.data('myoldvalue', elem.val());
   console.log('new-oldval', elem.data('myoldvalue')); //Some debugging code
});
```

You can then get the value with:

```
jQuery(input).data("myoldvalue");
```